# How to Format json out put in dom using angular in Ionic app?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am setting up a view for an ionic app so far everything is working i am getting this data to outputted to the dom.

```
{"total_number_machines":"167","chargine_machines":"67","defective_machines":"0","idle_machines":"100","total_revenue":"6565","todays_revenue":"800","total_number_of_bookings":"656","todays_number_of_bookings":"56"}
```

I want to format this for user readability for instance Total number of machine :Here this value has to be displayed("total_number_machines":"167")

As an  output example

```
Total Number Of machine:167
```

Same for the rest of the values My home code is  as follows.

```
<ion-content>
  <div class="ion-padding">
    <p>Details</p>

    <div class="row">{{ data ? data : '-' }}</div>
    <ng-template #errorContent><p><span style="color: red;">{{error}}</span></p></ng-template>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use built-in JSON pipe.

e.g:

```
<div>{{data | json}}</div>
```

[Angular JSON Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe)

For pretty printing you can use Another Approach `KeyValuePipe`:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of myArray"> 
    <!--element is an object-->
    <div *ngFor="let item of element|keyvalue">
        {{item.key}}:{{item.value}} <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Angular KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)

Edit:
Here is the Stackblitz working example:
[Key Value pipe Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-7ypcse)

Comment: This is fine but I want to output it like a table like one value per line with a div I could define

Comment: if you have same keys every Time your can wrap them in `<p>` tag it will automatically come in other line.

Comment: Can you show me an example for how will i use this for my code?

Comment: Please check my Answer i have added stackblitz link.

Comment: I have checked your answer here what i can see is this {{item.key}}:{{item.value}} Instead of that If i can impliment this directly like {{data.value}} sort of stuff then that will be more helpfull somthing like <p> Charging machine :{{data.chargine_machines}}</p> Somthing like this in html file.

Comment: You can do that. with simple `*ngFor`

Comment: I want an example code for that the data is already returned to dom with a json response that could be accessable like this `<div class="row">{{ data ? data : '-' }}</div>` I want to display only `chargine_machines` somthing like this `<div class="row">{{ data.charging_machines }}</div>`